# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. vb inserting data into access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

ok i'm trying to insert data into my access database and i'm getting this error

```
 Dim lnkr As New OleDbCommand(String.Format("insert into projet ([Student Name], [Days Absent], [Classes Absent], [Arabic], [Islamic], [English], [Math], [Biology],[Chemistry], [Physic], [Computer], [Day Offs] values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}')", TextBox1.Text, TextBox10.Text, TextBox12.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox9.Text, TextBox8.Text, TextBox11.Text))
    lnkr.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    lnkr.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: That is not the right way to build SQL or oass data.  Count the number pf placeholders (`{n}`) and items

Comment: I strongly recommend that you give the TextBoxes meaningful names. For example, `TextBox1` could be named `tbStudentName`. It would help you avoid programming errors.

Comment: The error message is very clear. It appears you should be spending time learning to count before you spend time programmingj; you have 12 columns in your SQL but are passing 13 values, and the message tells you **exactly** what the problem is; you should learn to actually read the words in the error messages, because they almost always have useful information in them.

Comment: Also, this code is very insecure and is vulnerable to Sql injection attacks.  Use a parameterized query instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have 12 Arguments, and 13 items {0}-{12}. 13 is not less than the size of the arguments list (12).